# libgdx project is giving error after importing in android studio 1.5.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

After building the project in libgdx setup,I imported that project in android studio but after importing it is giving error:

> Gradle 'test' project refresh failed Error:Could not initialize class
>   org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree

I don't know what is the problem